# Bug ID? Lower New York

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Found it on the floor of my basement laundry room in a mostly wooden house in the woods in Westchester County, NY. However I had done a mountain hike (same general area) and I may have brought it from there on my pants or something, but I'm not sure.

When it noticed me it stopped moving, but it was still alive because when I put it in this cup for a pic I accidentally flipped it upside down and it started squirming to get itself upright.

[image: Penny for scale]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not an insect but a crustacean (it has more than 6 legs).

It is a **[woodlouse (plural woodlice)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodlouse)**. A woodlouse is one of the few terrestrial isopode crustacean. There are about 5000 known species of woodlice. I have no idea which one is the one you captured!

[image]

Woodlice are generally appreciated in gardens as they control pests. They sometimes get inside searching for moisture. While it may not be pleasant to have woodlice at home (just because they look disgusting to many, me including), they do not spread disease or cause much damage.